# HTTP Status 500 – Internal Server Error. Ошибка при обработке команды. REST

Tags: java, rest, http-status-code-500

Доброго времени суток. Пишу (пытаюсь) простой чат на java с условием создания rest api. 
Функционал простой: регистрация, авторизация, общение в едином чате (без возможности создать комнаты), отправка файлов.
При регистрации пользователь вводит данные и нажимает на кнопку регистрации. Но после этого вылетает 500-я ошибка, текст которой привожу в приложенном изображении.

Разворачиваю проект на томкате.
[image: Ошибка 500]

Метод addUser класса ProfileResource представлен ниже

```
@GET
@Path("/reg")
@Produces("application/json")

        public void addUser(
        @QueryParam("username") String username,
        @QueryParam("firstname") String firstname,
        @QueryParam("lastname") String lastname ) throws SQLException {

    con.CreateTableProfile();
    con.CreateUser(username, firstname,lastname);
    System.out.println("Username:" + username);
    System.out.println("Firstname:" + firstname);
    System.out.println("Lastname:" + lastname);
}
```

В чём может быть ошибка? Я совсем зелёный новичок "в ресте". Очень прошу не кидать камни, а хотя бы пнуть в нужном направлении.

Comment: текстовую информацию лучше приводить в виде текста: и людям удобнее читать/копировать, и роботам — индексировать. для исправления нажмите [edit]

Comment: Тем более, что на скриншоте значимая часть ошибки обрезана.